# How to add run-time processing of @NotNull annotation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was quite surprised to see that IntelliJ actually does *runtime* verification of @NotNull within IDEA when running/debugging a unit test. Is it possible for me to add this same feature to my maven build? (What jars/jvm settings do I require?)

Answer (score 5):

IDEA is using its own method of instrumenting bytecode to add such validations. For command line builds we provide javac2 Ant task that does the instrumentation (extends standard javac task). If you generate Ant build from IDEA, you will have an option to use javac2.

[We don't provide similar Maven plug-in yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-31368), but [there is third-party version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/javac2) which may work for you (though, it seems to be a bit old).

Comment: Is javac2.jar a replacement for tools.jar ?

Comment: No, it's just an Ant task that extends Ant javac task by adding GUI forms and annotations instrumentation. The source code for this task is available in the IDEA Community Edition git repository.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there are way to switch the processing off for unit tests where I want to test null pointer behaviour? iE. `@org.junit.Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)` tests?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the AOP way:

First of all you need a [javax.validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) compatible validator ([Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) is the reference implementation).

Now create an aspectj aspect that has a Validator instance and checks all method parameters for validation errors. Here is a quick version to get you started:

```
public aspect ValidationAspect {

    private final Validator validator;

    {
        final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();

    }

    pointcut serviceMethod() : execution(public * com.yourcompany**.*(..));

    before() : serviceMethod(){
        final Method method = (Method) thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
        for(final Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()){
            if(arg!=null) validateArg(arg,method);
        }
    }

    private void validateArg(final Object arg, final Method method) {
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validationErrors = validator.validate(arg);
        if(!validationErrors.isEmpty()){
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Validation Errors in method ").append(method).append(":\n");
            for (final ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : validationErrors) {
                sb.append(" - ").append(constraintViolation.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(sb.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Use the [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) to weave that aspect into your test and / or production code.

If you only want this functionality for testing, you might put the aspectj-plugin execution in a profile.

Answer (score 1):

There is a maven plugin closely affiliated with the IntelliJ functionality, currently at https://github.com/osundblad/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin. It is discussed under the [IDEA-31368](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-6689) ticket first mentioned in CrazyCoder's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do annotation validation in your JUnit tests.

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

public class Temp {
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactory;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        localValidatorFactory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactory.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
        localValidatorFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
    @Test
    public void testLongNameWithInvalidCharCausesValidationError() {
        final ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        productModel.setLongName("A long name with\t a Tab character");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<ProductModel>> constraintViolations = localValidatorFactory.validate(productModel);
        Assert.assertTrue("Expected validation error not found", constraintViolations.size() == 1);
    }
}
```

If your poison is Spring, take a look at these [Spring Unit Tests](https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.context/src/test/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/ValidatorFactoryTests.java)